# SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'trip_user_master'

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

when I'm trying to make a relation I found this error
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'trip_user_master'. (SQL: select [trip].*, [trip_user_master].[user_master_UserID] as [pivot_user_master_UserID], [trip_user_master].[trip_id] as [pivot_trip_id] from [trip] inner join [trip_user_master] on [trip].[id] = [trip_user_master].[trip_id] where [trip_user_master].[user_master_UserID] = 9)

my usermaster model
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserMaster extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'UserID';

```
protected $fillable = [
    'UserName', 'UserPassword', 'UserRoles', 'UserEmailID', 'city', 'SSN', 'DriverLicense', 'FullName', 'imagePath', 'PhoneNumber', 'ImageUrl','DriverTotalRate'
];

protected $table = 'UserMaster';

public function trips_for_traveler()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Trip::class);
}

public function trips_for_driver()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Trip::class)->using(Reservation::class);
}
```

}

my trip model

```
    <?PHP

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Trip extends Model
    {
    protected $fillable = [
    'FromCity', 'ToCity', 'PlaceToMeet', 'DateOfTrip', 'TimeOfTrip', 'DriverId', 'TimeOfPost'
    ];

protected $table = 'trip';

public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserMaster::class);
}

public function travelers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserMaster::class)->using(Reservation::class);
}
```

}

my reservation model(many to many table's model)

```
    <?PHP

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Reservation extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'Reservation';

/**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = true;
```

}

my route

```
    Route::get('/reservation',function (){
$data = \App\UserMaster::find(9);
dd($data->trips_for_traveler);
```

});

Comment: The error is telling you that `trip_user_master` does not exist in the database as either a table or a view.

Comment: I working on an external database which replaced trip_user_master with reservation now I need some way to make a relationship without updating anything on the database